# Trouble ssh to virtual Ubuntu server from another computer

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I'm new to Linux and I'm trying to ssh from one computer to another.

I have two computers:

Computer A is running Windows 10 with VirtualBox running Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS

Computer B is running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Both computers are connected to my home router via Wi-Fi

I want to ssh into the VB Ubuntu server from computer B and I've having trouble.

VB Global Tools > Host Network Manager settings:

DHCP Server: Enable

Adapter: Configure Adapter Manually with IPv4 Address: 192.168.56.1 and IPv4 Network Mask: 255.255.255.0

Network Setting:

Enable Network Adapter: checked

Attached to: Host-only Adapter

Name: name of the adapter

VB Ubuntu Server's ssh and ssh-server is installed and running.  `service ssh status` indicates the service is active and it's listening on port 22.  Just to verify that ssh is running fine, I'm able to ssh into VB Ubuntu guest from host using port forwarding method and `ssh name@localhost` or `ssh name@127.0.0.1`

I assume the port forwarding method is not the solution if I want to ssh from one computer to another; just host to guest (I've tried this method out of desperation and I get the Connection refused error)

Back to the Host-only Adapter method.  After doing a `ifconfig` on the VB Server, I see my new IP address and tried to `ping` this address from the other computer and get the error:

> Time to live exceeded

If I do `ssh name@ip` I get

> ssh: connect to host ip port 22: Connection timed out

**What do I need to do to be able to ssh into the VB Ubuntu Server  from my other computer?**

Thanks

Comment: How about selinux and firewall...

Comment: @SivaPrasath not sure what selinux is but if you could elaborate.  Firewall on the router is set to allow ping and LAN to WAN, WAN to LAN are set to: Allow all.  Windows firewall is on for Domain, private and public network.

Comment: @ChairmanMeow Not the Windows firewall but the firewall for Ubuntu Server which is what you're trying to `ssh` to. On Ubuntu Server run `firewall-cmd --permanent ---zone=public --add-port=22/tcp` and then `firewall-cmd --reload`. That will open port 22 but to be sure, run `firewall-cmd --list-ports` and you should see port 22. Also, run `netstat -tanp | grep 22` and that should show `ssh` listening on port 22. To rule out `selinux`, open `/etc/selinux/config` with a text editor and change the line that says `SELINUX=enforcing` to `SELINUX=disabled`, reboot, and try again.

Comment: have you installed the ssh daemon?

Comment: @NasirRiley ssh is listening on port 22.  However, when I `nano` the selinux conf file `semanage.conf`, I don't see the line `SELINUX=enforcing` and there are no other conf file under `/selinux` directory.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro yes, both ssh and sshd is `active (running)` and `listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22` and `listening on :: port 22`

Comment: @ChairmanMeow Not `/selinux`. The directory is `/etc/selinux`. Inside, you'll see a file called `config` which is where you'll find the line.

Comment: Type `setenforce 0` and try ssh

Comment: @NasirRiley sorry, I didn't type out /etc/ but I was there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you  have your VM set to "Host only" for the network type.  This creates a virtual NIC for your host OS and sets up a private subnet, allowing host to VM communication but that is it.

You want to set up your VM as "Bridged" network - this will attach it to the host's NIC and let your router give your VM an address via DHCP.  It will be just like any other computer on your network.

Note that in some corporate/school environments as well as hotels, conference centers, internet cafes etc, some setups will block multiple IPs on one "port" or block multiple MAC addresses behind one "port".

Comment: Thank you so much, switching to "Bridged Adapter" worked!